# Sorting a linked list in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table in MySQL

```
id  previous
1   null
2   1
3   2
4   3
```

I would like to sort that in mysql -> so that in this case it returns 1,2,3,4. How to do that?

Comment: Unless you're using MySQL 8.0, there is no native support for recursion. As well as upgrading, options include joining the table to itself as often as could be required, writing a sproc, handling the recursion logic in application code, or switching to an alternativemodel, e.g. nested sets. All of these options have been widely discussed.

Comment: Ok cool - can you give me an example for MySQL 8

Comment: Actually, I can't because I'm still stuck in the past.

Comment: What if several records have the same parentId value? How to sort then? Secondly, do you want to return one record with a comma separated list, or one record per number?

Comment: Search for the most basic example of a "recursive with" in MySQL 8.0. Alternatively, you can use MariaDB 10.2.2 or newer.

Comment: Hey - thanks for the answer - I edited the question - parentId is missleading. It is actually a previousId - thus there will be no duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0:

```
with recursive my_node (id) as (
    select id from table_a where parent_id is null
    union all
    select a.id from my_node n join table_a a on n.id = a.parent_id
  )
select * from my_node;
```

Answer (score 2):

With MySql versions below 8 you could use a variable that changes during the execution of the query:

```
select @id := if((select @n := id from tab where coalesce(parentId, -1) = @id), @n, @n)
from   tab,
       (select @id := -1) init
```

Note that although the main `from` clause mentions the table (which I called `tab`) it does not actually select anything from it. It only serves to get that many results in the output. The logic is in the sub-query within the `select` clause: each time it executes the variable `@n` gets the *next* value based on the current `@id` value. -1 is reserved to match with `null`. That `@n` value is then put back into `@id`, ...etc.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/966157/1)

*Disclaimer*: there is no absolute guarantee that the order of execution is as expected, or that the engine will not try to cache a result, which would lead to unexpected results. This is just a sloppy work-around for the absence of recursive query support in MySql 5.7 and below.